# Web API Post method keeps looping

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a post method in my controller and it does the job correctly when I send a request from my client application. The only problem is, the method keeps looping for I don't know what reason. I tried to debug if my foreach loop had something to do with it but I believe it is not the case. I am not very familiar with web api much and I need your help.

Here is my post method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostMain(IList<IMF_Main> mainFromConsolidator)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, 2);

            using (var anthill = new AnthillConsolidatorEntities())
            {
                if (anthill.IMF_Session.Where(w => w.TableinSession == "IMF_Main" && w.Session == 1).Count() > 0)
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, 3);

                if (anthill.IMF_Session.Where(w => w.TableinSession == "IMF_Main").Count() == 0)
                {
                    var session = new IMF_Session();
                    session.TableinSession = "IMF_Main";
                    session.DateandTime = DateTime.Now;
                    session.Session = 1;
                    anthill.IMF_Session.Add(session);
                    anthill.SaveChanges();
                }

                var main = new IMF_Main();
                foreach (var item in mainFromConsolidator)
                {
                    if (anthill.IMF_Main.Where(w => w.ItemID == item.ItemID).Count() == 0)
                    {
                        main.BrandID = item.BrandID;
                        main.ItemID = item.ItemID;
                        main.CategoryID = item.CategoryID;
                        main.SubCategoryID = item.SubCategoryID;
                        main.ClassID = item.ClassID;
                        main.GenderID = item.GenderID;
                        main.CoaID = item.CoaID;
                        main.SubCoaID = item.SubCoaID;
                        main.First_SRP = item.First_SRP;
                        main.Current_SRP = item.Current_SRP;
                        main.Previous_SRP = item.Previous_SRP;
                        main.isSenior = item.isSenior;
                        main.isActive = item.isActive;
                        main.DateCreated = item.DateCreated;
                        anthill.IMF_Main.Add(main);
                        anthill.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

                anthill.IMF_Session.Remove(anthill.IMF_Session.Where(w => w.TableinSession == "IMF_Main" && w.Session == 1).FirstOrDefault());
                anthill.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 1); 
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with looping? If it does not stop, you either have an infinite operation, loop or recursion. One thing that helps is to just break with the debugger and look into callstack where you are and what is happening. Also, tracing (Debug.Writeline) in any loop you might suspect helps you. First thing to find out is what is taking the time, and then what is calling it. Fix should then be easy.

Comment: @AndreasReiff When I say it loops I mean that when It reaches the end of the method(return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 1), it goes back to the start of the method.

Comment: When you look at the stacktrace, does it call itself again (probably not)? Otherwise, it could be externally called again, e. g. by your client. Are you certain that that does not happen?

Comment: Ok, thank you @AndreasReiff